# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String1

Tags: java

Hello I am very new to java and I want to use a constructor, pass it with a parameter from another class.

But eclipse is giving me an error
"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String".

```
String sType = type[0]; 
String mName = type[1];
```

for the above

please could someone help me with the below and point out my mistakes?

```
public class M {
    String [] type= new String [2];

public M (String type) {            
            this.Type = Type.split("\\.");
            String sType = type[0]; 
            String mName = type[1];
            System.out.println(sType);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `Type`? Specifically `this.Type` on the first line of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two problems here. First, you've got:

```
this.Type = Type.split("\\.");
```

... which uses `Type` instead of `type`.

Next, you're using `type[0]` which is referring to the *parameter* called `type`, not the field.

You *could* fix it to:

```
public M(String type) {
    this.type = type.split("\\.");
    String sType = this.type[0]; 
    String mName = this.type[1];
    System.out.println(sType);
}
```

... but I'd seriously consider changing the name of the fields to `types` instead of `type` - or possibly a custom class, if this is an array that is always expected to have two elements with a specific meaning.

(I'm also *hoping* that your class isn't really called `M`...)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I missed typed type on here with capital letter in a hurry to post this.

Comment: @javaLearner101: Please take more time in future. Saving 30 seconds of your time at the expense of a minute of several other people's time (people who are trying to help you for free) is not a good idea. Ideally, come up with a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem, and make sure that you post the *exact* program which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have a problem with the capital letter T for Type.
The attribute is type and not Type

And you miss the keyword this.

```
String mName = this.type[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
this.Type = Type.split("\\.");
```

but there is no field name Type.

Answer (score 0):

This is plain lack of attention. The code contains tons of different variables called "Type" with lower and uppercase letters or letters added, etc. `type` is the argument passed to the constructor, which is a `String` and thus the error occurs. This code has a poor style. You should use more distinct names instead of different versions of "type".

Comment: Thanks for the feed back